Getting Missing biometric data as specified in “Uses” error with finguer print authntication
I'm taking finguerprint data with JS code and pass to UIDI for validation but it's sending back below error
Missing biometric data as specified in “Uses”
How to resolved this error ?
var XML = ' <PidOptions ver="1.0"> <Opts fCount="1" fType="0" iCount="0" pCount="0" format="0" pidVer="2.0" timeout="10000" posh="UNKNOWN" env="P" /> ' + DemoFinalString + ' </PidOptions>';

var verb = "CAPTURE";
var err = "";

var res;
$.support.cors = true;
var httpStaus = false;
var jsonstr = "";
$.ajax({

    type: "CAPTURE",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: finalUrl + MethodCapture,
    data: XML,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve]. It is hard to identify what is not working or what is expected presently.
